# Ubuntu Getting Mount error in VMWare workstation

Tags: 12.04, vmware

I'm getting errors when booting ubuntu. It worked fine for the past few months but suddenly stopped doing so. Here are the messages:

```
mount:mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/29a23397-e18d-441c-b138-340b48019991 on /root failed:Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed:No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed:No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed:NO such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requsted /sbin/init.
No init found.Try passing init=bootarg

Busybox v1.18.5 (ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1) built-in shell (ash)
(initramfs)
```

Please, help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might arise because of corruption of root file system and file system is not getting mounted.

Try This:

1.Boot from the Ubuntu Live CD;

2.Open/Run Terminal;

3.Type: `sudo fdisk -l` [ENTER] to get device name;

Determine the correct partition form output .For me it was "/dev/sda9"

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   102414335    51206144    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       102414436   625136791   261361178    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       102414438   212953484    55269523+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       212963328   357175295    72105984    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       409609368   625136791   107763712    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       403466240   409608191     3070976   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda9       357177344   403454687    23138672   83  Linux
```

4.Type: sudo fsck /dev/sda9[ENTER];

5.Restart the system

Comment: I am using Vmware how to Boot from USB. will you tell me the steps.Because all my work is in Ubuntu only

Comment: If you have an ISO image of ubuntu, mount it on CD-ROM.Now check for "Connected at power on" option for CD-ROM in vmware,  `VM` > `Settings` > `CD/DVD`. On the right side, there should be a couple check boxes for "Connected" and "Connect at power on." One more option in  power menu is "Power ON to BIOS" and if you choose that option, you will  get a virtual BIOS that lets you configure the boot order. Check both option and boot from the CD in live mode.